# Unity Button dont want to close a canvas

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello i made a canvas in unity.
when the player preses the Esc button a canvas opens
In the canvas i made a button when the player clicks on the button the 
Canvas need to close but nothing happens when i press the button.

Can somebody help me with this problem?

[The Canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEIx7.png)

```
 using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


public class PauseMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Canvas PlayerPauseMenu;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        PlayerPauseMenu = GetComponentInChildren<Canvas>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        HandleInput();

    }

    private void HandleInput()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            PlayerPauseMenu.enabled = true;

        }
    }
    public void CloseCanvas()
    {

            PlayerPauseMenu.enabled = false;  
    }

    }
```

Comment: Are you setting the TimeScale to 0 when the pause menu shows up?

Comment: No i dont do  that.

Comment: Not shure then, however one thing I did notice, Your comment on `FixedUpdate` says *"Update is called once per frame"*, that is incorrect. `FixedUpdate` gets called every phyisics update, this update can happen multiple times per frame. The normal `Update` function is the one that gets called once per frame. Can you update your code to show us the section that causes `CloseCanvas()` to get clicked?

Comment: I added an image for that.

Comment: Instead of using `PlayerPauseMenu.enabled` you should use `PlayerPauseMenu.SetActive()`.

Comment: I cant use SetActive().

Comment: `PlayerPauseMenu.gameObject.SetActive(false)` and `PlayerPauseMenu.gameObject.SetActive(true)`

Comment: Was @Programmer answer the solution you were looking for Jordi?